# I need to debug my Android app while not plugged into my computer

Tags: android, debugging, gps, logcat, ddms

So, let me start off by saying that I am 'relatively' familiar and comfortable with making Android apps and using both LogCat and DDMS to debug.

That being said, I'm encountering more of a logistical issue than anything else right now - I am making a locative app, where the GPS is fuelling and controlling other methods in my Activity, and after a while, it is crashing.

Now, because it is locative, I am walking around to test it, in order to receive different GPS locations. Because of this, I am not connected to my computer at the time that it crashes, so have no way (that I know of) to read the stack trace, etc.

In my particular instance, I am navigating through a series of activities, and finally reach the penultimate screen in my app, and while I am running the application in my studio, it runs indefinitely without issue. It is only when I take the device outside that it crashes...

I am wondering if anyone has any tips or tricks with this issue - I'm sure give the prevalence of locative apps, it must have come up, but I cant seem to find the right search terms. It could be as simple as saving the LogCat to file, and/or the stackTrace, but I'm not sure that's the answer...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can debug location ups using the emaulator and a GPX file. For crash reporting you might want to look into crash reporting libraries. i.e. crashalitics

Answer (score 4):

If I got you right, this is what you are looking for:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=de

Edit: Also there are many more apps like this. You can just browse around in Google Play Store

Comment: Hmmm.. thanks. I never thought to just check the Play Store. This particular app isn't very helpful - it doesn't seem to show much at all, and all the other ones require root, which unfortunately isn't an option on this device...

Comment: Oh okay... I just had apps like this at the back of my mind, I did not know that root is not an option.

Answer (score 4):

You can debug the app without rooting your android, unlike the other responses. start off by plugging the android into your computer, then run `adb devices` to make sure the device is there. Then, run `tcpip 5555` to change the android to tcp mode, which will allow debugging over wifi. Disconnect the android from the computer, and connect to it by typing `adb 192.168.x.xxx`, replacing the x's with your android's IP address. It should connect with no issues, as long as port 5555 is open, and both the android and your computer is on the same wifi.

Answer (score 3):

Simple: Wireless ADB

One of the reason that I choose to run CyanogenMod on my testing devices is that it is a stripped down version of Android that has some additional developer tools, one of those being the ability to access the wireless portion of the ADB system.

As you are probably unaware, you are able to establish an ADB connection to your device over WiFi, however, if running a stock ROM, this requires root access, as it can be potentially harmful to your device, as Wireless ADB will work even over your cellular network, meaning that you could potentially receive apps from other *insert carrier here*'s devices.

If you wish to run WirelessADB, [here is a Play Store app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rockolabs.adbkonnect) that will help you to enable the feature on your device. **Requires ROOT**

It is as simple as connecting your device to your local WiFi network, (same one the development computer is connected to), enable Wireless ADB, and then running the following command on your computer:

> adb connect 192.168.1.101

Replacing `192.168.1.101` with the IP address of your android device.

By establishing this connection, you can run everything just as you would if the device was plugged in via USB Cable.

Comment: Hmm... ok. I'm not rooted on this device. I've used the wireless adb to push code to a development device in the past, so may try that, thanks.

Comment: Hmm... separate question, but I wont be on WiFi... how would I get the IP of my phone on cellular data ? (jsut thinking out loud...)

Comment: If you run a ROM like Cyanogen mod... you can view that right in your ConnectionInfo, right next to the WirelessADB Button ^.-

Answer (score 1):

I recommend ACRA (Application Crash Reports for Android ). It allows you to send crash reports to a number of different destinations. See https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a decent tool,  but I'm an independent developer without a backed server (or the desire/need for one at least), so I'm going to try another solution. Will upvote though! ;-)